# Invocar un Component desde un evento click En angular 7

Tags: html, angular7

Lo que necesito es tener algo así,

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Aca <app-Recibos></app-Recibos></button>
```

podrán ver que soy novato con angular no se si se pueda hacer o alguna sugerencia para realizar esta acción.

lo que deseo es traer el component en el html donde tengo los botones y volverla a cerrar, seria algo como con un modalwindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu método onClick podría cabiar el estado de un flag:

```
onClick() {
  this.mostrarRecibos = !this.mostrarRecibos;
}
```

Y en tu plantilla podrías tener algo como

```
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
<app-Recibos *ngIf="mostrarRecibos"></app-Recibos>
```

Es una opción sencilla de implementar, pero si quieres un modal de verdad te recomiendo mirar angular material o ng-bootstrap, ambos tienen en su catálogo de componentes formas de crear modales.

Comment: Gracias y mirare el modal de ng-boostrap